# body tag background image suggestion required

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have a new website layout from our Customer. But the Layout contains a 1280X1795pxs Landscape as a background image. And the Customer don't wants to change this background.

Now My question is what will be the best practice to use this image as background?

So that the page speed is optimized too and load time is also optimized.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well how large is the image file size? Aside from changing the compression used on the image to reduce it, there is nothing HTML/CSS wise that you can do. Just let the browser cache it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this image doesn't have to change the best solution is to use adapted cache-control whith htaccess:http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-cache-control.html.

Answer (score 0):

IF you're using PHP for your website then use apc cache mechanism to store images in cache, or using any framework use default mechanism of frameworks for caching.

Sanil S

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the image is of, simple image compressing techniques and choosing the right file format can help greatly.

If you've got yourself a nice pattern, try and find where it repeats, and crop the image to that size. Then, in your the CSS of your page, simply add to the body:

```
body { background: url("pattern.jpg") repeat-all; }
```

If you have a pattern that repeats in only one direction, such as a "column" pattern that must only repeat downwards, then use

```
body { background: url("column.png") repeat-y #your-background-rgb-colour; }
```

And this will make it repeat down the page, but not across. The same goes for repeating the image across the page, just use repeat-x.

Next, to image formats. Now this is where we get really subjective, but here's my take on it. You have four main options:

1. **.jpg** Use this for images that have to be photo-realistic, without any colour clipping. For web viewing, generally you can use around 70% quality.
2. **.gif** For an image that only needs a set number of colours. Gif images can be very small, but at the expense of losing unnecessary colours from the image.
3. **.png (Limited Palette)** This png format works in the same manner as the gif that I described above, but in some circumstances this can produce a smaller result.
4. **.png (Full-bit)** Similar to jpg, this png format allows for all colours and photo-realistic images. However it generally provides a larger image than jpg, but with less compression artefacts (blocky bits in the image).

Just play around with compression settings and you'll find something pleasing, though.

Nathan C.